# Creating an Observer and notify my subscribers

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient

I need to provide a function that returns an Observer to subscribe to.
In this function, I use an API call that returns an Observer that I'm registering to.
I need to notify my Observer subscribers after analyzing the data I got from the Observer that I'm registered to.

Here is my code, How I should notify my subscribers?

```
public isLoggedIn() : Observable<User>
  {
    let myobs : Observable<any> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      let obs : Observable<any> ;   
      obs = this.webservice.getAuthorized<isLoggedInResponse>(this.isLoggedInServiceName, null, UserService.user.requestToken) ; //This is a code that use httpClient and get's it's Observable
      obs.subscribe((response : isLoggedInResponse) =>{           
        if(response.loggedInUser)
        {    
          //Here i need to notifty myobs's subscribers on success                          
        }           
        else
        {
          //Here i need to notifty myobs's subscribers on failure
        }
      });
    });
    return myobs;
  }
```

Comment: Use `observer.next(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Well here is my updated code :

```
let myobs : Observable<any> = Observable.create((observer ) => {
      let obs : Observable<any> ;
        
      obs = this.webservice.getAuthorized<isLoggedInResponse>(this.isLoggedInServiceName, null, UserService.user.requestToken) ;
      
      obs.subscribe((response : isLoggedInResponse) =>{   
        localStorage.removeItem(UserService.USER_DATA_TOKEN);
        if(response.loggedInUser)
        {    
          observer.next(response.loggedInUser);                                  
        } 
        else{
          observer.error();
        }  
        observer.complete();        
      });
    });
    return myobs;
```